# how to change xaml textbox dynamically?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I made an enum for the state of the program.
When it is set for JustInstalled, I am trying to change an XAML label's content using C#.

CS code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using System.IO;

namespace WpfApplication3
{
    enum Status
    {
        JustInstalled, 
        Configured
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            Status status = new Status();
            if (!File.Exists("logindata.xml"))
            {
                status = Status.JustInstalled;
                if (status == Status.JustInstalled)
                {
                   Application.Current.Resources["loginlabel"].Content = "Please enter your desired username and password.";
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication3.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication3"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="DFIHUDF" Height="350" Width="525"

        >
    <Grid>
        <Label FontSize="20" x:Name="label" Content="SFDGFDS" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="180,10,0,0" Width="209"/>
        <Label x:Name="loginlabel" Content="x" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="84,95,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="89"/>

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

The 2 errors were:

```
Error   CS1061  'object' does not contain a definition for 'Content' and no extension method 'Content' accepting a first argument of type 'object' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) WpfApplication3 C:\Users\Nathan\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\WpfApplication3\WpfApplication3\MainWindow.xaml.cs    44
```

and

```
Error   CS0017  Program has more than one entry point defined. Compile with /main to specify the type that contains the entry point.    WpfApplication3 C:\Users\Nathan\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\WpfApplication3\WpfApplication3\obj\Debug\App.g.i.cs  63
```

I have no idea what the errors are talking about, as I am new to WPF, and my main problem here is that I don't know how to dynamically change the  content of a label with c#.

Comment: what you are trying to do???... you needs to create an instance of your "WpfApplication3.MainWindow" and then set the label Content property

Comment: You're gonna dig yourself a big ole hole if you carry on down this route dude.  Start looking at MVVM.  Start with MVVMLight.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As I see you do not need to introduce additional stuffs like enums here, The following will sufice:

```
  public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            if (!File.Exists("logindata.xml"))        
                StatusText = "Just Installed";  
            else
                StatusText = "Configured"; 


            DataContext = this; 
        }

    public string StatusText {get;set;}
}
```

Then your label:

```
<Label x:Name="loginlabel" Content="{Binding StatusText}" />
```

Comment: StatusText changes won't be noticed by the XAML...  There is no property changed being handled, so the binding will only work once, when the constructor is called.  Any other changes to StatusText will be ignored by the UI..  Need a DependencyProperty or to call OnPropertyChanged and implement INotifyPropertyChanged.

Comment: @Curtis, I agree, but my solution was based on the current requirements and this binding will be needed only one time, so in this case any other added piece will be over engineering.

Answer (score 1):

You need to have a mechanism to update the text when your StatusText property changes.  This can be done by using a Dependency Property and binding.

First, put this binding in your XAML:

```
<Label x:Name="loginlabel" Content="{Binding StatusText}" />
```

Next, add a dependency property to your code so that the XAML will know about changes:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty StatusTextProperty = 
DependencyProperty.Register("StatusText", typeof(string), typeof(Window1));

public string StatusText
{
    get
    {
        return this.GetValue(StatusTextProperty) as string;
    }
    set
    {
        this.SetValue(StatusTextProperty, value);
    }
}
```

Lastly, add a method to allow for the dynamic setting of the new status:

```
public void UpdateStatus()
{
    if (!File.Exists("logindata.xml"))
    {
        StatusText = "Please enter your desired username and password.";
    }
    else
    {
        StatusText = "Logged In";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public class Program
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            WpfApplication3.MainWindow win = new WpfApplication3.MainWindow();
            Status status = new Status();
            if (!File.Exists("logindata.xml"))
            {
                status = Status.JustInstalled;
                if (status == Status.JustInstalled)
                {
                   win.loginlabel.Content = "Please enter your desired username and password.";

                }

                Application.Run(win);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: You'd need to add the [x:FieldModifier](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970905(v=vs.110).aspx) to the label for that to work .